# How to set separating line's color of GridView on Android

Tags: android, gridview

I use below code to set line separating the cells of the grid:

```
GridView gv = (GridView)findViewById(gridview id);
gv.setVerticalSpacing(3);
gv.setHorizontalSpacing(3);
gv.setAdapter(Adapter);
```

It only set line width, but not show different color.
How can I do to set different color line?

Comment: maybe changing the gridview BG works for you!

Comment: hey have you find any Solution !!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with the grid. You'll have to remove the separator and add a border to the view that you can change for each view.